# React Developer Tools says 'Proxy Component' instead of the name of the component

Tags: reactjs, webpack, webpack-hmr, webpack-hot-middleware

I am using `Webpack` with `Hot Module Reloading`. I also use the chrome extension `React Developer Tools` to inspect the react tree while developing. When I inspect the page and look at the component tree, I would like to see the name of the actual components, however, for every component the name shows up as `Proxy Component`.

I can let you know more specifics about my `Webpack`, but I am struggling to even google the right thing to solve this issue.

Here are the tools I am using for webpack:

```
"webpack": "^1.9.6",
"webpack-dev-middleware": "^1.2.0",
"webpack-dev-server": "^1.14.1",
"webpack-hot-middleware": "^2.0.0"
```

***webpack.config.js***

```
var path = require('path');
var webpack = require('webpack');

module.exports = {
  devtool: 'eval',
  entry: [
    'webpack-hot-middleware/client',
    './client/index'
  ],
  output: {
    path: path.join(__dirname, 'static'),
    filename: 'bundle.js',
    publicPath: '/static/'
  },
  plugins: [
    new webpack.HotModuleReplacementPlugin(),
    new webpack.NoErrorsPlugin()
  ],
  module: {
    loaders: [
      {
        test: /\.json$/,
        loader: 'json'
      },
      {
        test: /\.js$/,
        loader: 'babel-loader',
        include: path.join(__dirname, 'client'),
        query: {
          plugins: ['transform-runtime'],
          presets: ['es2015', 'stage-0', 'react', 'react-hmre']
        }
      },
      {
        test: /\.scss$/,
        loaders: ['style', 'css', 'sass']
      }
    ]
  }
};
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried to assign the `displayName` property?

```
export const Navbar = (props) => {
  let title = null;
  let menu = null;

  return (
    <header className={style.navbar}>
      <Grid>
        <Row>
          <Col xs={12} sm={12} md={12} lg={12}>
            {title}
            {menu}
          </Col>
        </Row>
      </Grid>
    </header>
  );
};

Navbar.displayName = 'Navbar'; // LIKE THIS

Navbar.propTypes = {
  title: PropTypes.string,
  items: PropTypes.arrayOf(PropTypes.node),
};
```

Comment: Interesting. That did work for warning messages in the console, but it did not work for the React Developer Tools.

Comment: I'm not sure what can be the problem, check if this helps: https://github.com/facebook/react-devtools/issues/4#issuecomment-31553158

Comment: I ended up going through every single file and giving every single component a display name (seemed tedious.. is there a webpack plugin for this?) and it worked. Thank you!

Answer (score 4):

I think it's because you should have set the node environnement variable to 'production'. In production mode, React renames your components and they are displayed as ProxyComponent in React Developer Tools.

**EDIT**

Your problem is with the hot module replacement and React Transform. As stated by [Dan Abramov](https://medium.com/@dan_abramov/hot-reloading-in-react-1140438583bf#.nou6sjwfv) himself, when using Hot Reloading for React the components need to be proxied, and the display name of the proxied component is derivated from the `displayName` of your components. That's why it works when you add an explicit `displayName`, if you don't, React devtools will fall back to the `ProxyComponent` module's name : `ProxyComponent`.

Comment: Are you sure ? Can you paste your webpack config file please ?

Comment: Sure I have added it to the end of my question.